# Не создается виртуальное окружение на Windows 10

Tags: python, virtualenv

При создании виртуального окружения через `virtualenv` на windows10 получаю ошибку:

```
Андрей@DESKTOP-9UJCU9T E:\ttt
$ virtualenv venv
Using base prefix 'c:\\python'
New python executable in E:\ttt\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 939, in call_subprocess
    line = line.decode(encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 38: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 192, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\python\Scripts\virtualenv.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 860, in main
    create_environment(
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1173, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs, download=download)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1019, in install_wheel
    _install_wheel_with_search_dir(download, project_names, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1110, in _install_wheel_with_search_dir
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=script)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 941, in call_subprocess
    line = line.decode(fs_encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 38: invalid start byte
```

`virtualenv` установлен в системе глобально

```
Андрей@DESKTOP-9UJCU9T E:\ttt
$ virtualenv --version
16.7.6
```

версия `python`:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.8.0
```

OS Windows 10 x64
что примечательно на версии `python-3.7.5` все работает. Но мне бы хотелось использовать последнюю версию питона))

Может посоветуете как решить проблему?

Comment: `line = line.decode(fs_encoding)` где-то в путях папка на русском языке. Возможно юзер винды на русском, а глобальные установки скешировались в его AppData

Comment: да, папка юзера на русском. Но можно ли как-то обойти эту проблему?

Comment: Пробовал опцию `--no-cache-dir` не помогает..

Comment: Попробуйте для начала в переменных среды винды сменить папку TEMP и TMP на (например) c:\tmp . Эта папка тоже в юзерском аппдата по умолчанию. Может ему это мешает?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov спасибо вам большое, помогло ) напишите ответ, а я отмену решением )))